# tap UIwebView and don't dimiss keyboard

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, keyboard

When I tap UIWebView, the keyboard will disappear, This is not What I want , I want the keyboard remain there, any solution?

Comment: does the keyboard have a reason for being there?  is there a text field or some other place for input from it to go?

Comment: When I tap UIwebView, I want to remove the textView and the keyboard which is the first responder of textView, but the result is that the keyboard disappear  while the textView remain. I have the solution to remove the textView. but the keyboard and textView  don't go away simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

If you want your keyboard to disappear when you remove your text view, make sure to call `resignFirstResponder` on your text view before you remove / release your text view.

If you are touching the UIWebView while the text view is visible, then the *focus* changes from the text view to the web view and the keyboard dismisses, since the OS believes that any touches happening from that point are meant for the web view.  If you touch the text view (if it's still visible, that is), the focus changes back to the text view and the keyboard should re-appear.

If these answers don't help you, please clarify your question.